# How to set up an linear chart in Scala FXML controller?

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am trying to build a ScalaFX application displaying a linear chart.

I have defined the line chart controller member as

```
@javafx.fxml.FXML
private val lineChart: XYChart = _
```

And am trying to add data with

```
val data = ObservableBuffer(Seq(
  (1, 23),
  (2, 14),
  (3, 15)
) map {case (x, y) => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](x, y).delegate} )

val series = XYChart.Series[Number, Number]("My series", data)
lineChart.data.set(series)
```

But I get 2 errors here:

First Idea highlights "series" (in `lineChart.data.set(series)`) and says "Type mismatch, expected: ObservableList[XYChart.Series[X, Y]], actual XYChart.Series[Number, Number]"

Second - when I try to build I get "unbound placeholder parameter private val lineChart: XYChart = _" error.

Any suggestions?
                                   ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answers myself, let me share them for anybody who may be having the same problems.

- Use `var`, not `val`
- Use the LineChart type, not XYChart
- Specify the chart axes types
- Use `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart`, not `scalafx.scene.chart.LineChart` (would be nice if anybody could suggest the right way with ScalaFX though)

Wrong:

```
private val lineChart: XYChart = _
```

Right:

```
private var lineChart: LineChart[Number, Number] = _
```

- Use `lineChart.getData.add(series)`, not `lineChart.data.set(series)`
- Set `fx:controller` to the controller full name in the FXML code (not added by Scene Designer)

It works as expected then.